# Index(Match( on multiple criteria (Column D or Column E)

Tags: excel

I've been trying to solve this for a few days in excel. I have an Access table connected in the layout shown below:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUIig.png]

This has thousands of rows of data which I would like to filter/Index(Match( by 2 different columns.

I need this to meet the criteria of:

```
IF Sheet2!A1 = Column D or Column E
```

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Do you mean **IF Sheet2!A1 = Sheet1!D:D or Sheet1!E:E** ?

Comment: Does http://www.exceltactics.com/vlookup-multiple-criteria-using-index-match/ or http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/10/28/multi-condition-vlookup/ help or do I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the worksheet where you want your results, put this formula into column A on an unused row.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$9999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9999)+(((Sheet1!$D$1:$D$9999<>Sheet2!$A$1)+(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$9999<>Sheet2!$A$1))=2)*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill right and down as necessary to catch all available values from Sheet1 that meet Sheet1's column D or column E having the value in Sheet2!A1.

To use a ListObject Table's structure cell references, you will have to adjust the row returned by 1 to compensate for the header row of the table. For the first column (e.g. Season) this would be,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table_All_FootballResults.accdb, SMALL(INDEX(ROW(Table_All_FootballResults.accdb[Season])-1+(((Table_All_FootballResults.accdb[Home]<>Sheet2!$A$1)+(Table_All_FootballResults.accdb[Away]<>Sheet2!$A$1))=2)*1E+99, ,  ), ROW(1:1)), COLUMN(A:A)), "")
```

Fill both right and down.

Comment: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2ec2hlc.jpg
I have reworded it for you in here, If you have an answer for this it would be a great help